# Aggregating key value pair in python

Tags: python, key-value, aggregation

I have a question related to python code.
I need to aggregate if the key = kv1, how can I do that?

```
input='num=123-456-7890&kv=1&kv2=12&kv3=0'
result={}
for pair in input.split('&'):
(key,value) = pair.split('=')
if key in 'kv1':
   print value
   result[key] += int(value)
print result['kv1']
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Did you mean "if key == 'kv1':"?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it did not work.

Comment: You realize that you don't have a 'kv1' in your example input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant `key == 'kv1'` and also the `kv` within `input` was meant to be `kv1` and that `result` is an empty `dict` that doesn't need `result[key] += int(value)` just `result[key] = int(value)`

```
input = 'num=123-456-7890&kv1=1&kv2=12&kv3=0'
keys = {k: v for k, v in [i.split('=') for i in input.split('&')]}

print keys # {'num': '123-456-7890', 'kv2': '12', 'kv1': '1', 'kv3': '0'}

result = {}
for key, value in keys.items():
    if key == 'kv1':

        # if you need to increase result['kv1']
        _value = result[key] + int(value) if key in result else int(value)
        result[key] = _value

        # if you need to set result['kv1']
        result[key] = int(value)

print result # {'kv1': 1}
```

Assuming you have multiple lines with data like:

```
num=123-456-7890&kv1=2&kv2=12&kv3=0
num=123-456-7891&kv1=1&kv2=12&kv3=0
num=123-456-7892&kv1=4&kv2=12&kv3=0
```

Reading line-by-line in a file:

```
def get_key(data, key):
    keys = {k: v for k, v in [i.split('=') for i in data.split('&')]}
    for k, v in keys.items():
        if k == key: return int(v)
    return None

results = []

for line in [line.strip() for line in open('filename', 'r')]:
    value = get_key(line, 'kv1')
    if value:
        results.append({'kv1': value})

print results # could be [{'kv1': 2}, {'kv1': 1}, {'kv1': 4}]
```

Or just one `string`:

```
with open('filename', 'r') as f: data = f.read()

keys = {k: v for k, v in [i.split('=') for i in data.split('&')]}

result = {}
for key, value in keys.items():
    if key == 'kv1':
        result[key] = int(value)
```

Console i/o:

```
c:\nathan\python\bnutils>python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def get_key(data, key):
...     keys = {k: v for k, v in [i.split('=') for i in data.split('&')]}
...     for k, v in keys.items():
...         if k == key: return int(v)
...     return None
...
>>> results = []
>>> for line in [line.strip() for line in open('test.txt', 'r')]:
...     value = get_key(line, 'kv1')
...     if value:
...         results.append({'kv1': value})
...
>>> print results
[{'kv1': 2}, {'kv1': 1}, {'kv1': 4}]
>>>
```

test.txt:

```
num=123-456-7890&kv1=2&kv2=12&kv3=0
num=123-456-7891&kv1=1&kv2=12&kv3=0
num=123-456-7892&kv1=4&kv2=12&kv3=0
```

Comment: If you need to increment `result[key]` you will need to first check if there is a key with that name in `result` first. `if key in result: result[key] += int(value) else: result[key] = int(value)`

Comment: If I wanted the same code to be read from a file, how I can do it.crs = open("file.txt", "r")
keys = {k: v for k, v in [i.split('=') for i in crs.read().split('&')]}

print keys # {'num': '123-456-7890', 'kv2': '12', 'kv1': '1', 'kv3': '0'}

result = {}
for key, value in [s.strip for s in keys.items()]:
    if key == 'kv1':
        result[key] = int(value)

print result # {'kv1': 1}

Comment: Updated the answer to show how to do this by reading line-by-line from a file.

Comment: bnlucas.. It does not work .. it gives following error.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    keys = {k: v for k, v in [i.split('=') for i in data.split('&')]}
  File "test.py", line 3, in <dictcomp>
    keys = {k: v for k, v in [i.split('=') for i in data.split('&')]}
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: I have updated the answer to show the console input/output of the code, which is working for me. What version of Python are you on?

Answer (score 0):

```
import urlparse
urlparse.parse_qs(input)
```

results in: {'num': ['123-456-7890'], 'kv2': ['12'], 'kv': ['1'], 'kv3': ['0']}

The keys are aggregated for you.

Comment: Can I do without urlparse? Also, I need to aggregate the value only for kv1 not for all.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way, so basically just add an extra if else block dealing with the empty case for key

```
input='num=123-456-7890&kv=1&kv2=12&kv3=0'
result={}
for pair in input.split('&'):
    temp = pair.split('=')
    key = temp[0]
    value = [1]
    if key in 'kv1':
        if key in p:
             print value //do you really want to output this?
             result[key] += int(value)
        else:
             print value //do you really want to output this?
             result[key] = int(value)
print result['kv1']
```

Comment: typo P should be result, 

if key in result: