# Reading from file to parse key value pair

Tags: python, file, key-value

I need to parse the file. The code does not work for me.
The file has following values.

```
num=123-456-7890&kv1=1&kv2=12&kv3=0
num=123-456-7890&kv4=1&kv2=12&kv3=0
num=123-456-7890&kv1=10&kv2=12&kv3=0



crs = open("file.txt", "r")
keys = {k: v for k, v in [i.split('=') for i in crs.read().split('&')]}

print keys 

result = {}
for key, value in [s.strip for s in keys.items()]:
    if key == 'kv1':
       result[key] = int(value)

print result
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the answer on your other question for this [Aggregating key value pair in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034243/aggregating-key-value-pair-in-python/17034483#17034483) for reading from a file.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit: Only the sum of the values of kv1 and kv2 is needed

Use a `defaultdict` to avoid checking for existence of a key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(int)
for line in crs:
    data = {k: v for k, v in (i.split('=') for i in line.split('&'))}
    for key in ['kv1', 'kv2']:
        res[key] += int(data.get(key, 0))
```

Now `res` contains:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'kv2': 36, 'kv1': 11})
```

Access like a normal dict:

```
>>> res['kv1']
11
>>> res['kv2']
36
```

## Previous solutions

You can do this in one line:

```
>>> [{k: v.strip() for k, v in [i.split('=') for i in line.split('&')]} 
     for line in crs]
[{'kv1': '1', 'kv2': '12', 'kv3': '0', 'num': '123-456-7890'},
 {'kv2': '12', 'kv3': '0', 'kv4': '1', 'num': '123-456-7890'},
 {'kv1': '10', 'kv2': '12', 'kv3': '0', 'num': '123-456-7890'}]
```

If you need only `'kv1'`, you can filter for it directly:

```
>>> [{k: int(v) for k, v in [i.split('=') for i in line.split('&')] 
     if k == 'kv1'} for line in crs]
[{'kv1': 1}, {}, {'kv1': 10}]
```

Comment: How will aggregate the values, I need to print out the following values, num, total of kv1 and kv2

Comment: Updated my solution. I could not find any hint in your question that you are looking for the sums. There is no `+` or `sum` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your new solution. Unfortunately, your solution does not work in terms of num. I need to print out num, and aggregate values of kv1 and kv2.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would like to have. I am sure it can be optimized better

```
crs = open('file.txt','r')
result={}
k1 = 0
k2 = 0
for line in crs.read().strip().split('\n'):
    for pair in line.split('&'):
        (key,value) = pair.split('=')
        if key in ('kv1','kv2'):
           if key == 'kv1':
              k1 += int(value)
              result[key] = int(k1)
           else:
              k2 += int(value)
              result[key] = int(k2)
        else:
             result[key] = value

print result['num']+'&'+'kv1='+str(result['kv1'])+'&'+'kv2='+str(result['kv2'])
```